# Dynamic population in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view, in which I have 1 column as template field, while other 8 columns are dynamically created.
This template field has a checkbox, while trying to retrieve this checkbox in code-behind file, we get it as null.

When columns are not dynamically created, the checkbox is pretty fine and has a value in code behind.
Below is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridResultSet" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true"
                    OnRowCreated="GridResultSet_RowCreated" OnLoad="GridResultSet_Load" CssClass="reportGrid"
                    CellPadding="4" OnSorting="GridResultSet_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="GridResultSet_RowDataBound">
                      <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reclass">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <acesec:CheckBox ID="chkReclass" CssClass="CheckBoxListStyle" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                     </Columns>
            <RowStyle CssClass="gridrow" />
     <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridrow" />
  <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridheader" />  
</asp:GridView>

System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chbReclass = gridResultSet.Rows[i].FindControl("chkReclass") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox;
```

Do I need to check something in order to access a template field while creation of dynamic columns?

Any body faced same kind of situation?

Pointers will be highly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Your checkbox in the TemplateField is not being bound to anything.  How are you setting its value?

Comment: which event are you trying to access this control in??

Comment: @Dinesh I am trying to access this control in the onclick event of a button..

Comment: @Garrison: I don't need to set its value, I m just trying to access this checkbox in the onclick event of a button and if it exists then, I am trying to bind the dynamic columns to the grid view

Comment: I'm guessing it's not showing in the data because it's not bound to anything, so .NET isn't sending it back across the wire, but I'm not sure.  Could you explain the purpose of your application so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Garrison and Dinesh...I was able to achieve the required functionality in a different way..Thanks for paying heed to my question.. tats why Stack Overflow rocks...Regards